# Meaning of 'The function value is not a list of numbers with dimension 3 at the given point' in the context of this differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I'm attempting to model the motion of a figure skater, and currently have to solve this differential equation, numerically, for an angular velocity vector, (in the skater's reference frame), and I'm having trouble understanding why this differential equation is failing to solve.

Here is the equation:

```
  sol = NDSolve[{(Li'[
             t] + ℐ'[
              t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[
               t]} + ℐ[
              t].{ωx'[t], ωy'[t], ωz'[t]} + 
            Cross[{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}, 
             Li[t] + ℐ[
                t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}]).ê0 == 
         0, (Li'[t] + ℐ'[
              t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[
               t]} + ℐ[
              t].{ωx'[t], ωy'[t], ωz'[t]} + 
            Cross[{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}, 
             Li[t] + ℐ[
                t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}]).ê1 == 
         0, (Li'[t] + ℐ'[
              t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[
               t]} + ℐ[
              t].{ωx'[t], ωy'[t], ωz'[t]} + 
            Cross[{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}, 
             Li[t] + ℐ[
                t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}]).ê2 == 
         0, ωx[0] == ωx0, ωy[
          0] == ωy0, ωz[0] == ωz0}, {ωx[
         t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}, {t, 1, 2}, 
       Method -> {"Automatic", {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}}];
```

From this full code:

Oh also, the run time is massive (on my computer anyways) - probably because I'm not yet sure what I'm doing and whilst creating it routinely copied and pasted almost the exact same formula 19 times in many cases, then went in and slightly changed them all by hand. I've hit command period each time due to this, not sure if it's causing my errors but I don't think so.

So anyways, it says:
a) that some function value is not a list of numbers with dimension 3 at the given point. But I'm stumped as to why, since the output does appear to be three components... unless the <<1>> means that there's an expression that it hasn't evaluated, due to an abort, thus, classifying it as not a valid triplet of numbers? I've gotten conflicting messages about this point though. The error message just took me back to the Mathematica page for ND Solve, which doesn't appear to help.
b) I don't know what Function Value means in this context; I've read the documentation, but still only have a fuzzy idea of what it is.
c) Something about *Unable to find initial conditions that satisfy the residual function with specified tolerences.* So I don't know why it's saying that, but I *think* it's secondary to my problem, and I may be able to change that later - but I have a feeling I might not know until I can handle the error message about the .

One other thing, I've already read and tried some of the different dif. eq. solving techniques that I managed to find [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveRigidBody.html) (In fact if you go to the beginning of the big long code and change ϕ13[t] from t to 0, you can actually get this as a special case just fine), and just blindly followed some of the error messages so that I have now gotten rid of them. I say this because it reminds me a that, while this is just a conceptual question, why does the code work fine if the guy isn't moving, but as soon as I make something move it fails to work? I look to forwards to getting better at learning how to use mathematica.

Please tell me if I ought to include more information!

Thanks in advance

**Edit/Update:** So since I started writing this question, I have actually solved the problem of having a massive run time, but now I have completely different problem. It says "Recursion depth of 1024 exceed during the evaluation" (?!? I don't even think I added anything that was recursive...). (Tell me if I should change the title in light of this)

**Edit 2:** Try this for the full code instead, it solves the problem in the (first) edit, and gets back to the title of my question:

<No longer here, see below>

**My third edit: This is the exact error message** The function value {-5.55196*10^7-105398. {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}.0,-4.24184*10^6+75422.4 {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}.0,0.} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {3} at {t,ωx[t],ωy[t],ωz[t],(ωx^′)[t],(ωy^′)[t],(ωz^′)[t]} = {0.,0.,0.,6.,0.,0.,0.}.

So... now it *definitely* doesn't look like a list of numbers with dimension 3, but still no clue as to why, or why 'function value' keeps popping up here.

**Another Edit:** I've solved everything since my first edit now, with this code:

```
Remove["Global`*"]; 

θ1[t_] = 0; ϕ1[t_] = 0; ψ1[t_] = 0;
θ2[t_] = 0; ϕ2[t_] = 0; ψ2[t_] = 0;
θ3[t_] = 0; ϕ3[t_] = 0; ψ3[t_] = 0;
θ4[t_] = 0; ϕ4[t_] = 0; ψ4[t_] = 0;
θ5[t_] = 0; ϕ5[t_] = 0; ψ5[t_] = 0;
θ6[t_] = 0; ϕ6[t_] = 0; ψ6[t_] = 0;
θ7[t_] = 0; ϕ7[t_] = 0; ψ7[t_] = 0;
θ8[t_] = 0; ϕ8[t_] = 0; ψ8[t_] = 0;
θ9[t_] = 0; ϕ9[t_] = 0; ψ9[t_] = 0;
θ10[t_] = 0; ϕ10[t_] = 0; ψ10[t_] = 0;
θ11[t_] = 0; ϕ11[t_] = 0; ψ11[t_] = 0;
θ12[t_] = 0; ϕ12[t_] = 0; ψ12[t_] = 0;
θ13[t_] = 0; ϕ13[t_] = (Pi/4) t; ψ13[t_] = 0;
θ14[t_] = 0; ϕ14[t_] = 0; ψ14[t_] = 0;
θ15[t_] = 0; ϕ15[t_] = 0; ψ15[t_] = 0;
θ16[t_] = 0; ϕ16[t_] = 0; ψ16[t_] = 0;
θ17[t_] = 0; ϕ17[t_] = 0; ψ17[t_] = 0;
θ18[t_] = 0; ϕ18[t_] = 0; ψ18[t_] = 0;
θ19[t_] = 0; ϕ19[t_] = 0; ψ19[t_] = 0;

β2 = 0.50044;
β11 = 0.88494;
λ2 = 7.2;
λ3 = 2.6;
λ4 = 2.6;
λ5 = 17;
λ6 = 17;
λ7 = 11.75;
λ8 = 11.75;
λ9 = 7.5;
λ10 = 7.5;
λ11 = 6.5;
λ12 = 19;
λ13 = 19;
λ14 = 14;
λ15 = 14;
λ16 = 10.5;
λ17 = 10.5;
λ18 = 2;
λ19 = 9;

Λ2 = 12.5;
Λ3 = 17.25;
Λ4 = 17.25;
Λ5 = 9.7;
Λ6 = 9.7;
Λ7 = 29;
Λ8 = 29;
Λ9 = 27.5;
Λ10 = 27.5;
Λ11 = 11;
Λ12 = 15;
Λ13 = 15;
Λ14 = 41;
Λ15 = 41;
Λ16 = 40;
Λ17 = 40;
Λ18 = 16;
Λ19 = 11;

M = {30631*(13/28), 30631*(12/28), 0, 0, 1887, 1794, 1002, 971, 324, 
   383, 30631*(3/28), 5839, 5601, 2288, 2182, 807, 793, 0, 4025};

Ā = {{9315, 14436, 2643}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {146, 132, 
    23}, {136, 126, 20}, {62, 67, 6}, {52, 54, 6}, {5.3, 4.5, 
    1.6}, {5.7, 5.7, 1.7}, {0, 0, 0}, {964, 942, 132}, {1086, 1034, 
    171}, {286, 283, 25}, {310, 290, 35}, {29.6, 5.5, 35.7}, {28.8, 
    5.6, 30.7}, {0, 0, 0}, {144, 181, 207}};

ωx0 = 0;
ωy0 = 0;
ωz0 = 6;

a[t_] = {{θ1[t], ϕ1[t], ψ1[t]}, {θ2[
     t], ϕ2[t], ψ2[t]}, {θ3[t], ϕ3[t], ψ3[
     t]}, {θ4[t], ϕ4[t], ψ4[t]}, {θ5[
     t], ϕ5[t], ψ5[t]}, {θ6[t], ϕ6[t], ψ6[
     t]}, {θ7[t], ϕ7[t], ψ7[t]}, {θ8[
     t], ϕ8[t], ψ9[t]}, {θ9[t], ϕ9[t], ψ9[
     t]}, {θ10[t], ϕ10[t], ψ10[t]}, {θ11[
     t], ϕ11[t], ψ11[t]}, {θ12[t], ϕ12[
     t], ψ12[t]}, {θ13[t], ϕ13[t], ψ13[
     t]}, {θ14[t], ϕ14[t], ψ14[t]}, {θ15[
     t], ϕ15[t], ψ15[t]}, {θ16[t], ϕ16[
     t], ψ16[t]}, {θ17[t], ϕ17[t], ψ17[
     t]}, {θ18[t], ϕ18[t], ψ18[t]}, {θ19[
     t], ϕ19[t], ψ19[t]}};

Eθ[t_] = 
  Table[{{Cos[a[t][[s, 1]]], -Sin[a[t][[s, 1]]], 
     0}, {Sin[a[t][[s, 1]]], Cos[a[t][[s, 1]]], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {s, 
    19}];
Eϕ[t_] = 
  Table[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[a[t][[s, 2]]], -Sin[a[t][[s, 2]]]}, {0, 
     Sin[a[t][[s, 2]]], Cos[a[t][[s, 2]]]}}, {s, 19}];
Eψ[t_] = 
  Table[{{Cos[a[t][[s, 3]]], 0, -Sin[a[t][[s, 3]]]}, {0, 1, 
     0}, {Sin[a[t][[s, 3]]], 0, Cos[a[t][[s, 3]]]}}, {s, 19}];
R[t_] = Table[(Eθ[t][[s]]).(Eϕ[t][[s]]).(Eψ[
       t][[s]]), {s, 19}];

B1[t_] = R[t][[1]];
B2[t_] = B1[t].R[t][[2]];
B3[t_] = B2[t].R[t][[3]];
B4[t_] = B2[t].R[t][[4]];
B5[t_] = B3[t].R[t][[5]];
B6[t_] = B4[t].R[t][[6]];
B7[t_] = B5[t].R[t][[7]];
B8[t_] = B6[t].R[t][[8]];
B9[t_] = B7[t].R[t][[9]];
B10[t_] = B8[t].R[t][[10]];
B11[t_] = B1[t].R[t][[11]];
B12[t_] = B11[t].R[t][[12]];
B13[t_] = B11[t].R[t][[13]];
B14[t_] = B12[t].R[t][[14]];
B15[t_] = B13[t].R[t][[15]];
B16[t_] = B14[t].R[t][[16]];
B17[t_] = B15[t].R[t][[17]];
B18[t_] = B2[t].R[t][[18]];
B19[t_] = B18[t].R[t][[19]];


B[t_] = {B1[t], B2[t], B3[t], B4[t], B5[t], B6[t], B7[t], B7[t], 
   B8[t], B9[t], B10[t], B11[t], B12[t], B13[t], B14[t], B15[t], 
   B16[t], B17[t], B18[t], B19[t]};


ê0 = {1, 0, 0};
ê1 = {0, 1, 0};
ê2 = {0, 0, 1};

ê3 = {-Sin[β2], 0, Cos[β2]};
ê4 = {Sin[β2], 0, Cos[β2]};

ê12 = {-Sin[β11], 0, -Cos[β11]};
ê13 = {Sin[β11], 0, -Cos[β11]};



u1 = {0, 0, 0};
u2 = λ2 ê2;
u3 = -λ3 ê0;
u4 = λ4 ê0;
u5 = -λ5 ê2;
u6 = -λ6 ê2;
u7 = -λ7 ê2;
u8 = -λ8 ê2;
u9 = -λ9 ê2;
u10 = -λ10 ê2;
u11 = -λ11 ê2;
u12 = -λ12 ê2;
u13 = -λ13 ê2;
u14 = -λ14 ê2;
u15 = -λ15 ê2;
u16 = λ16 ê1;
u17 = λ17 ê1;
u18 = λ18 ê2;
u19 = λ19 ê2;


U2 = Λ2 ê2;
U3 = Λ3 ê3;
U4 = Λ4 ê4;
U5 = -Λ5 ê0;
U6 = Λ6 ê0;
U7 = -Λ7 ê2;
U8 = -Λ8 ê2;
U9 = -Λ9 ê2;
U10 = -Λ10 ê2;
U11 = -Λ11 ê2;
U12 = Λ12 ê12;
U13 = Λ13 ê13;
U14 = -Λ14 ê2;
U15 = -Λ15 ê2;
U16 = -Λ16 ê2;
U17 = -Λ17 ê2;
U18 = Λ18 ê2;
U19 = Λ19 ê2;

Γ[t_] = {u1, U2 + B2[t].u2, U2 + B2[t].U3 + u3, 
   U2 + B2[t].U4 + u4, U2 + B2[t].U3 + B3[t].U5 + B5[t].u5, 
   U2 + B2[t].U4 + B4[t].U6 + B6[t].u6, 
   U2 + B2[t].U3 + B3[t].U5 + B5[t].U7 + B7[t].u7, 
   U2 + B2[t].U4 + B4[t].U6 + B6[t].U8 + B8[t].u8, 
   U2 + B2[t].U3 + B3[t].U5 + B5[t].U7 + B7[t].U9 + B9[t].u9, 
   U2 + B2[t].U4 + B4[t].U6 + B6[t].U8 + B8[t].U10 + B10[t].u10, 
   U11 + B11[t].u11, U11 + B11[t].U12 + B12[t].u12, 
   U11 + B11[t].U13 + B13[t].u13, 
   U11 + B11[t].U12 + B12[t].U14 + B14[t].u14, 
   U11 + B11[t].U13 + B13[t].U15 + B15[t].u15, 
   U11 + B11[t].U12 + B12[t].U14 + B14[t].U16 + B16[t].u16, 
   U11 + B11[t].U13 + B13[t].U15 + B15[t].U17 + B17[t].u17, 
   U11 + B11[t].U13 + B13[t].U15 + B15[t].U17 + B17[t].U18 + 
    B18[t].u18, U2 + B2[t].U18 + B18[t].U19 + B19[t].u19};



Print["Body Center of Gravity Coordinates="];
\[ScriptCapitalC][
   t_] = (Sum[(M[[s]]) (Γ[t][[s]]), {s, 
      19}])/(Sum[(M[[s]]), {s, 19}]);
Print["List of segments' C.M. from body Center of Gravity \
Coordinates="];
Ω[t_] = 
  Table[(Γ[t][[s]]) - \[ScriptCapitalC][t], {s, 19}];
Print["Inertia matrix="];
ℐ[t_] = 
  Sum[(B[t][[s]]).(DiagonalMatrix[{Ā[[s, 1]], Ā[[s, 2]], 
        Ā[[s, 3]]}]).(Inverse[
       B[t][[s]]]) + (M[[s]]) ((Norm[Ω[
             t][[s]]]^2) IdentityMatrix[3] - 
       Outer[Times, Ω[t][[s]], Ω[
          t][[s]]]), {s, 19}];
Print["Whole-Body Inertia Matrix:[ℐ[t]]="];
MatrixForm[ℐ[t]];
Print["Eigenvectors[ℐ[t]], in Matrix Form="];
MatrixForm[Eigenvectors[ℐ[t]]];
Print["Eigenvalues[ℐ[t]]="]; 
Eigenvalues[ℐ[t]]; 


Print["ωs[t]="]; 
ωs[t_] = 
  Table[{((B'[t][[s]]).(Inverse[B[t][[s]]]))[[3, 
      2]], ((B'[t][[s]]).(Inverse[B[t][[s]]]))[[1, 
      3]], ((B'[t][[s]]).(Inverse[B[t][[s]]]))[[2, 1]]}, {s, 19}];


Print["Lis[t]:="];
Lis[t_] = 
  Table[Cross[Ω[t][[s]], 
     M[[s]]*Ω'[t][[s]]] + 
    B[t][[s]].DiagonalMatrix[{Ā[[s, 1]], Ā[[s, 2]], 
       Ā[[s, 3]]}].Inverse[B[t][[s]]].ωs[t][[s]], {s, 19}];


Print["Internal/observed Angular Momentum="];

Li[t_] = Sum[Lis[t][[s]], {s, 19}];

Print["Differential Equation Solution ="];

sol = NDSolve[{(Li'[
         t] + ℐ'[
          t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[
           t]} + ℐ[
          t].{ωx'[t], ωy'[t], ωz'[t]} + 
        Cross[{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}, 
         Li[t] + ℐ[
            t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}]).ê0 == 
     0, (Li'[t] + ℐ'[
          t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[
           t]} + ℐ[
          t].{ωx'[t], ωy'[t], ωz'[t]} + 
        Cross[{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}, 
         Li[t] + ℐ[
            t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}]).ê1 == 
     0, (Li'[t] + ℐ'[
          t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[
           t]} + ℐ[
          t].{ωx'[t], ωy'[t], ωz'[t]} + 
        Cross[{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}, 
         Li[t] + ℐ[
            t].{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}]).ê2 == 
     0, ωx[0] == ωx0, ωy[
      0] == ωy0, ωz[0] == ωz0}, {ωx[
     t], ωy[t], ωz[t]}, {t, 0, 6}, 
   Method -> {"Automatic", {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}}];

VectorQ[sol[[1]]]

Plot[{ωx[t], ωy[t], ωz[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 6}, 
 PlotRange -> All]

Print["ω[t]:="];
ω[t_] = {ωx[t] /. 
    FilterRules[sol[[1]], ωx[t]], ωy[t] /. 
    FilterRules[sol[[1]], ωy[t]], ωz[t] /. 
    FilterRules[sol[[1]], ωz[t]] }; 

Print["Absolute angular momentum vector, as viewed from the skater's \
frame of reference="]; 

L[t_] = Li[t] + ℐ[t].ω[t]; 


(* draw 'frame man' with line segments between nodes, plus extra \
lines to shoulders and hips from edges of abdomen region*)

Print["Plot Manipulate"];
(*Manipulate[Graphics3D[{Line[{{0,0,0},U2}],Line[{U2,U2+B2[t].U3}],\
Line[{U2+B2[t].U3,U2+B2[t].U3+B3[t].U5}],Line[{U2+B2[t].U3+B3[t].U5,\
U2+B2[t].U3+B3[t].U5+B5[t].U7}],Line[{U2+B2[t].U3+B3[t].U5+B5[t].U7,\
U2+B2[t].U3+B3[t].U5+B5[t].U7+B7[t].U9}],Line[{U2+B2[t].U3+B3[t].U5+\
B5[t].U7+B7[t].U9,U2+B2[t].U3+B3[t].U5+B5[t].U7+B7[t].U9+B9[t].u9}],\
Line[{U2,U2+B2[t].U4}],Line[{U2+B2[t].U4,U2+B2[t].U4+B4[t].U6}],Line[{\
U2+B2[t].U4+B4[t].U6,U2+B2[t].U4+B4[t].U6+B6[t].U8}],Line[{U2+B2[t].\
U4+B4[t].U6+B6[t].U8,U2+B2[t].U4+B4[t].U6+B6[t].U8+B8[t].U10}],Line[{\
U2+B2[t].U4+B4[t].U6+B6[t].U8+B8[t].U10,U2+B2[t].U4+B4[t].U6+B6[t].U8+\
B8[t].U10+B10[t].u10}],Line[{U2+B2[t].U3,U2+B2[t].U18}],Line[{U2+B2[t]\
.U4,U2+B2[t].U18}],Line[{U2+B2[t].U18,U2+B2[t].U18+B18[t].U19}],Line[{\
U2+B2[t].U18+B18[t].U19,U2+B2[t].U18+B18[t].U19+B19[t].u19}],Line[{{0,\
0,0},U11}],Line[{U11,U11+B11[t].U12}],Line[{U11,U11+B11[t].U13}],Line[\
{U11+B11[t].U12,U11+B11[t].U12+B12[t].U14}],Line[{U11+B11[t].U13,U11+\
B11[t].U13+B13[t].U15}],Line[{U11+B11[t].U12+B12[t].U14,U11+B11[t].\
U12+B12[t].U14+B14[t].U16}],Line[{U11+B11[t].U13+B13[t].U15,U11+B11[t]\
.U13+B13[t].U15+B15[t].U17}],Line[{U11+B11[t].U12+B12[t].U14+B14[t].\
U16,U11+B11[t].U12+B12[t].U14+B14[t].U16+B16[t].u16}],Line[{U11+B11[t]\
.U13+B13[t].U15+B15[t].U17,U11+B11[t].U13+B13[t].U15+B15[t].U17+B17[t]\
.u17}],Line[{U11+B11[t].U12,U11+B11[t].u11}],Line[{U11+B11[t].U13,U11+\
B11[t].u11}],Line[{U11,U11+B11[t].u11}],Point[Ω[t]],\
Blue,Thick,Line[{Ω[t],Ω[t]+(10^(-6))(\
Eigenvalues[ℐ[t]].ê0)Eigenvectors[ℐ[t]\
].ê0}],Green,Thick,Line[{Ω[t],Ω[t]+(10^(-\
6))(Eigenvalues[ℐ[t]].ê1)Eigenvectors[\
ℐ[t]].ê1}],Red,Thick,Line[{Ω[t],\
Ω[t]+(10^(-6))(Eigenvalues[ℐ[t]].ê2)\
Eigenvectors[ℐ[t]].ê2}],Blue,Thick,Line[{\
Ω[t],Ω[t]-(10^(-6))(Eigenvalues[\
ℐ[t]].ê0)Eigenvectors[ℐ[t]].ê0}],\
Green,Thick,Line[{Ω[t],Ω[t]-(10^(-6))(\
Eigenvalues[ℐ[t]].ê1)Eigenvectors[ℐ[t]\
].ê1}],Red,Thick,Line[{Ω[t],Ω[t]-(10^(-6))\
(Eigenvalues[ℐ[t]].ê2)Eigenvectors[ℐ[\
t]].ê2}],Yellow,Thick,Arrow[{Ω[t],Ω[t]+(\
10^(-5))Li[t]}],Purple,Thick,Arrow[{Ω[t],Ω\
[t]+(10^(-6))L[t]}],Orange,Thick,Arrow[{Ω[t],\
Ω[t]+15ω[t]}],Arrow[{Ω13[t],\
Ω13[t]+150 ω13[t]}]} \
,PlotRange\[Rule]{{-150,150},{-150,150},{-150,150}},SphericalRegion\
\[Rule]True,RotationAction\[Rule]"Clip",AxesEdge\[Rule]{{-1,-1},{-1,-\
1},{-1,-1}},Axes\[Rule]True,AxesLabel\[Rule]{x,y,z}],{t,0,3}]*)
```

So now that this is short enough to post, I'm back to exactly my original problem again, just as I described it before these couple of edits.

Comment: Looks like the recursion is this bit: `Ω[t_] = Γ[t] - Ω[t]`

Comment: @SimonWoods I just saw that too. Thanks.

Comment: The uppercase omega on the right hand side should be a capital script C from right before it in the calculation

Comment: Also that line should be written differently so that it combines

Comment: I *may* have found the problem, it could be that I left some ambiguous parenthesis.

Comment: Could this problem have to do with NumericQ?

Comment: Can you illustrate your post with actual mathematical equations you are trying to solve. It may be one can write your equations in MA in much more shorter form, and this can solve your problem.

Comment: I think the issue is coming from all the `Abs` terms in the inertia matrix (produced by `Norm`). Try `\[ScriptCapitalI][t_] = \[ScriptCapitalI][t] /. Abs[x_]^2 :> x^2`

Comment: @SimonWoods I just saw that too, I think that that was it. I had just changed Norm squared to the vector dot itself which worked too, but I like what you did much better, thanks.

Comment: @yarchik sorry, I just got back to this. I don't actually have them written out all together, all in full.